Hiding file name in upload_file in pywebio
I am making a simple web app using PyWebIO library and I encountered an issue. I need to hide the filename when I am using the file_upload function from PyWebIO. I've tried many methods however, the filename is still displayed everytime user uploads a file.
This is how I am calling it:
    image = file_upload("Select an image:", accept="image/*", max_size='1M',required=True)

I tried making a function that changes filename to **** using onchange however that didn't work.
